# JavaMail vs GmailService

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have been reading about sending emails in Java and, as I have seen, I should use `OAuth` to make my app more secure. Later I discovered `XOAuth` which allows you to use `OAuth` with `JavaMail` but I don't get the difference.

As long as I know, if I want to use Gmail API I have to build my `Credential` object and a GmailService as:

```
public static Gmail getGmailService() throws IOException {
    Credential credential = authorize();
    return new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
}
```

After that, I could use the returned object to send emails or whatever I want to.

If I want to use `JavaMail` with `XOAuth` instead, I have to build my `Credential` object, get its accessToken and add it as a property (with some more) to the javax.mail.Session I will use to send the email (which is the purpose this time)

But I can't figure out which is better and its advantages

[XOAuth](https://github.com/bshannon/JavaMail/wiki/OAuth2)

[Google API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java?hl=es-419)

Comment: Note that JavaMail OAuth2 instructions are [here](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2).  The pros and cons of the JavaMail API vs. the Gmail API seems like a topic for a different forum.